# Extract date,month,year and month name from the unix timestamp with postgresql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, psql

I use postgres for the rails app and I have a `unix timestamp` in postgresql db. I have a requirement to select and `group by` the `dd-mm-yyyy` and by `month name`.

Consider I have the following unix timestamp

> 1425148200

and I would need to change this to datetime and I used `to_timestamp` which returned

> 2015-02-28 18:30:00 UTC

and I tried to convert the `datetime` to `local timezone` using

> ::timestamp without time zone AT TIME ZONE 'IST'

but that did not give time in required timezone and instead it returned

> 2015-02-28 16:30:00 UTC

and I tried to get the date part using `::date` which returned

> Sat, 28 Feb 2015

So please help me get the `dd-mm-yyyy` in specified `timezone` and month name(March) from the unix timestamp.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `did not return time in required timezone` - what does it mean? what return?

Comment: I have updated the result of :timestamp without time zone AT TIME ZONE 'IST'

Comment: Would this: `select DATE(to_timestamp(1425148200))` be what you want? This would return `2015-02-28`, date in format requested by you.

Comment: Welcome to TimeZone hell of Ruby(Rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select to_char(to_timestamp('1425148200')::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC-5:30','DD-MM-YYYY & of course Month')

> 01-03-2015 & of course March

It is postgres mistake I guess
according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/static/timezones.html
[image]

Comment: The time corresponding to '1425148200' in IST is "3/1/2015, 12:00:00 AM GMT+5:30" but it gives as 2015-02-28 20:30:00 UTC

Comment: @Logesh there are four time zones with ISTabbreviation. postgres knows Israel one

Comment: Yes, I looked into that and I could somehow solve this with the solution that you gave and I also tried getting the offset and adding to timestamp and that too works. Thanks anyway.